# How to specify the data type that data already in Hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, sqldatatypes

I have the data in hive that i dont know what the data type must be, so all of my data are String datatype, i want to know what the datatype in each field should be, like this example:

- all field in this sample are string
- so how should i do, if i want to know what is the datatype should be , like "msisdn" is bigint and "gender" is string and "age" is int and etc

[image]

Comment: Why did you label with MySQL and SQL is you are asking a Hive question?

Comment: maybe it can be solve with Sql languange

Comment: Are you working with Hive or SQL?